# Problemas con mi formulario

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Soy novato en programación, estoy intentando realizar un formulario de registro con HTML y CSS, generalmente las propiedades son de Bootstrap, el problema que tengo es que cuando veo el formulario en la pantalla de mi notebook se ve "bien" o cumple con el objetivo de lo que busco, sin embargo, al verlo en otras resoluciones, se ve horrible.

Pongo un extracto del código, generalmente todo lo demás se replica bajo el mismo formato pero cambiando los lbl e inputs.

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="container col-lg-4">
            <h2 style="margin-top: 10px; color:white; text-align: center;margin-bottom: 5%;">Formulario de registro</h2>
            <form name="message" method="POST" action="/registro/create2">
                <section class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                        <label style=color:white; for="rut" class="label_registro_izq">Rut (sin puntos con guion)</label>
                        <input id="txt_rut" type="text" value="" name="rut" class="input_registro_izq"
                            placeholder="Ingrese su rut">
                        <p><small id="lbl_rut" class="form-text text-danger lbl_izq">Por favor complete este
                                campo</small>
                        </p>
                        <p><small id="lbl_rut2" class="form-text text-danger lbl_izq">El rut ingresado no es
                                valido</small>
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la forma "horrible" y la "linda"? Es dificil poder ayudarte cuando no sabemos cómo quisieras que se vea. Usa el botón [edit] y agrega esta información

Comment: la gracia de bootstrap es saberlo usar, e intentar prescindir de CSS personalizado en lo posible.  Veo que usas una clase **class="input_registro_izq"** que vete a saber lo que hace, pero no es de bootstrap. Los inputs en bootstrap se ven mejor usando la clase **form-control**, independientemente de si van a la izquierda o derecha, pues eso lo debes controlar con mas rows/cols anidadas, o bien con clases de bootstrap de alineamiento

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@ a la comunidad. Creo que faltan detalles para comprender tu caso, por ejemplo, qué versión de Bootstrap usas o un poco más de código para tratar de replicar el comportamiento actual vs el esperado. Mientras editas tu pregunta, puedes ver en la documentación oficial el sistema de grillas que usa Boostrap.

Comment: En la página oficial de bootstrap hay ejemplos de codigo de formularios yo diria que te guies con ellos, solo es seguir la estructura

Comment: Agradezco a cada uno de ustedes el intentar ayudarme y hacerlos perder parte de su valioso tiempo. No estoy muy familiarizado con la plataforma y no sé como subir más imágenes respecto al problema, lo otro, es que al intentar colocar más código, me critica que existe un exceso de este y no me deja publicarlo por eso solo coloque un fragmento T_T.  Intentaré ver la forma de como hacerles llegar mas información.

Comment: Te recomiendo que empieces con un [layout base para tu formulario](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/), y que luego vayas personalizando **según el espíritu de Bootstrap**. Digo esto porque usar estilos in-line, como haces con algunos de tus elementos, es totalmente contrario al propósito de Bootstrap y en  general, es contrario a la programación moderna. Asimismo etiquetas como `small`, `center`, y otras no son recomendables hoy día. [He aquí ejemplos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#headings) para poner cabeceras (`h1, h2`...), `small`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

yo también soy muy novato en la programación pero creo que tu problema se debe a que a la hora de usar medidas, estas usando medidas fijas en vez de medidas variables. "px" es una medida fija por ejemplo y "em" es una medida variable que corresponde a 16px aunque dicha correspondencia puede ser modificada. Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!